# How to set icon for a file?

Tags: android

I am creating different types of Files. For example File extension as.txt, .doc, .xml, .java, .jpg, .png, and etc. How to set the icon to be matched with the files. For example i am creating one pdf file. How to set pdf icon to that pdf file.

Comment: If you aren't also creating the file browser then I think there is no way for you to specify what gets used as an icon.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to explicitly set icons for the files, unless you are creating file with your own extension.

The operating system will understand the file type and binds the icon accordingly.

That is why in windows, if you manually change a file's extension, the icon changes automatically. Same case applies to Android also.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create different files via your android app & want to show the files list along with icon as we can see it in Windows OS, then you have to put all different images of each file extension in drawable folder. example- pdfImage.png, jpgImage.png, pngImage.png etc. Now you have to process the file name to determine the file extension runtime. then update your iconView (an `ImageView` item) like:

```
iconView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); // bitmap is the Bitmap image
```

or

```
iconView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pdfImage_icon);
```